# Creating multiple parallel lines using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I'm using the following code to create multiple parallel lines

```
import arcpy, math

offset = 3
offset_original = offset
features=[]
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

infc="Export_Output_4_SmoothLine"
talhao = "Export_Output_5"

spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference

def CopyParallel(plyP,sLength):
    part=plyP.getPart(0)
    lArray=arcpy.Array();rArray=arcpy.Array()
    for ptX in part:
        dL=plyP.measureOnLine(ptX)
        ptX0=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL-0.01).firstPoint
        ptX1=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL+0.01).firstPoint
        dX=float(ptX1.X)-float(ptX0.X)
        dY=float(ptX1.Y)-float(ptX0.Y)
        lenV=math.hypot(dX,dY)
        sX=(-dY*sLength/lenV);sY=dX*sLength/lenV
        leftP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X+sX,ptX.Y+sY)
        lArray.add(leftP)
        rightP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X-sX, ptX.Y-sY)
        rArray.add(rightP)
    array = arcpy.Array([rArray, lArray])
    section=arcpy.Polyline(array, spatialRef)
    return section


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for shp in cursor:
        i=0
        while i <= 100:
            print str(i)
            if (i > 0):
                offset = offset + offset_original
            twoLines=CopyParallel(shp[0],offset)
            temp=twoLines
            features.append(twoLines)
            i=i+1

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "test")
```

It happens that after a while he starts to create lines in this way

[image]

How do I get these intersections or not create them in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I use to offset polygon features.  It should provide you with what you need.  Take note that this works on polygon geometry types, and should be modified for use with polylines.  I obtained much needed information from [here](http://pyright.blogspot.com/2011/02/simple-polygon-offset.html) and [here](https://geonet.esri.com/message/163494?commentID=163494#comment-163494?q=bug%20Creating%20polygons%20with%20holes%20using%20Arcpy).  Also, it needs updating, to take advantage of the data access module.

```
import math, os, arcpy
from arcpy import env

def calcoffsetpoint(pt1, pt2, offset):
    theta = math.atan2(pt2[1] - pt1[1], pt2[0] - pt1[0])
    theta += math.pi/2.0
    return (pt1[0] + math.cos(theta) * offset, pt1[1] + math.sin(theta) * offset)

def getoffsetintercept(pt1, pt2, m, offset):
    """From points pt1 and pt2 defining a line in the Cartesian plane, the slope of the line m,
    and an offset distance, calculates the y intercept of the new line offset from the original."""
    x, y = calcoffsetpoint(pt1, pt2, offset)
    return y - m * x

def getpt(pt1, pt2, pt3, offset):
    """Gets intersection point of the two lines defined by pt1, pt2, and pt3; offset is the
    distance to offset the point from the polygon."""
    ### Get first offset intercept
    if pt2[0] - pt1[0] != 0:
        m = (pt2[1] - pt1[1])/(pt2[0] - pt1[0])
        boffset = getoffsetintercept(pt1, pt2, m, offset)
    else: # if vertical line (i.e. undefined slope)
        m = "undefined"

    ### Get second offset intercept
    if pt3[0] - pt2[0] != 0:
        mprime = (pt3[1] - pt2[1])/(pt3[0] - pt2[0])
        boffsetprime = getoffsetintercept(pt2, pt3, mprime, offset)
    else: # if vertical line (i.e. undefined slope)
        mprime = "undefined"

    ### Get intersection of two offset lines
    if m != "undefined" and mprime != "undefined":
        # if neither offset intercepts are vertical
        newx = (boffsetprime - boffset)/(m - mprime)
        newy = m * newx + boffset
    elif m == "undefined":
        # if first offset intercept is vertical
        newx, y_infinity = calcoffsetpoint(pt1, pt2, offset)
        newy = mprime * newx + boffsetprime
    elif mprime == "undefined":
        # if second offset intercept is vertical
        newx, y_infinity = calcoffsetpoint(pt2, pt3, offset)
        newy = m * newx + boffset
    elif m == "undefined" and mprime == "undefined":
        # if both offset intercepts are vertical (same line)
        newx, y_infinity = calcoffsetpoint(pt1, pt2, offset)
        newy = pt2[1]

    return newx, newy

def offsetpolygon(polyx, offset):
    """Offsets a clockwise list of coordinates polyx distance offset to the outside of the polygon.
    Returns list of offset points."""
    polyy = []
    # need three points at a time
    for counter in range(0, len(polyx) - 3):
        # get first offset intercept
        pt = getpt(polyx[counter],
                   polyx[counter + 1],
                   polyx[counter + 2],
                   offset)
        # append new point to polyy
        polyy.append(pt)
    # last three points
    pt = getpt(polyx[-3], polyx[-2], polyx[-1], offset)
    polyy.append(pt)
    pt = getpt(polyx[-2], polyx[-1], polyx[0], offset)
    polyy.append(pt)
    pt = getpt(polyx[-1], polyx[0], polyx[1], offset)
    polyy.append(pt)
    return polyy

inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)          #input shapefile
outFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)         #output shapefile
offset_dist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)   #double, offset distance (in map units) UNICODE

### convert offset_dist to float
offset_dist = float(offset_dist)

### Print progress
spat = arcpy.Describe(inFC).spatialReference
units = spat.linearUnitName
arcpy.AddMessage("Offsetting %s %s..." % (offset_dist, units))

### Enable overwrite authority
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

### Create output shapefile by copying input shapefile
arcpy.Copy_management(inFC, outFC)

### Create empty Array objects
parts = arcpy.Array()
rings = arcpy.Array()
ring = arcpy.Array()

### Create cursor and update vertex coordinates
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(outFC)
shapefield = arcpy.Describe(outFC).shapeFieldName

### Loop through features of inFC
for row in cursor:
    newPartList = []
    # loop trough parts of feature
    for part in row.getValue(shapefield):
        coordList = []
        counter = 0
        # loop through points in part
        for pnt in part:
            if counter == 0: #skip first point
                counter += 1
            else:
                if pnt:
                    coordList.append((pnt.X, pnt.Y))
                    counter += 1
                else: #null point, denotes beginning of inner ring
                    counter = 0 #reset counter
                    offsetList = offsetpolygon(coordList, offset_dist) #calculate offset points
                    newPartList.append(offsetList) #add coordinates to new list
                    coordList = [] #empty list

        ### Add final (or only) offset coordinates for part
        offsetList = offsetpolygon(coordList, offset_dist)
        newPartList.append(offsetList)

    ### loop through newPartList, to create new polygon geometry object for row
    for part in newPartList:
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                ring.add(arcpy.Point(pnt[0], pnt[1]))
            else: #null point
                rings.add(ring)
                ring.removeAll()

        ### if last ring, add it
        rings.add(ring)
        ring.removeAll()

        ### if only one ring, remove nesting
        if len(rings) == 1:
            rings = rings.getObject(0)

        parts.add(rings)
        rings.removeAll()

    ### if single-part, remove nesting
    if len(parts) == 1:
        parts = parts.getObject(0)

    ### create polygon object based on parts array
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(parts)
    parts.removeAll()

    ### replace geometry with new polygon object
    row.setValue(shapefield, polygon)

    ### update cursor
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```