# Create offset polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, offset

I am looking for a method that enables to create offset polygons with a defined distance in ArcGIS. Like in Sketch Up, it allows to create the exact same shaped polygon as its input (selected) polygon.

I know there is a buffer tool, but it creates curves at certain points. This can be solved by MBR if the polygon is rectangle, but I expect to have random shapes.

The image below is what I'd like to get as a result, offset polygon inside of existing ones no matter what the polygon shape is. I hope to have everything in straight line that parallel to existing polygon.

I was considering using point array that is re-calculated from the original points, but this might be inaccurate when polygon is not simple rectangles.

Any advice..?

[image]

Comment: It requires using python, but see my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/231121/18981).

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Scale Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/scaling-a-feature.htm):

> You can scale a feature—make the entire feature larger or
>   smaller—using the Scale tool.

Also take a look at this question: [Is there ArcPy tool for polygon resizing like Scale tool of Advanced Editing toolbar in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/is-there-arcpy-tool-for-polygon-resizing-like-scale-tool-of-advanced-editing-too)
One of the answers is providing Python code for resizing.

Comment: Hi Bera, thank you for your comments. I want to apply this for multiple data, so probably I will check the python code.